# How can I fix expected type 'string', got unconvertible type '[]interface {}'?

Tags: terraform

Here's the code sample that I use:

`main.tf`

```
module "bar" {
   ...
   nets   = "${module.foo.nets_ids}"
}
```

`variables.tf`

```
variable "nets" {
  description = "nets desc."
  type        = "list"
}
```

`module bar's main.tf`

```
data "template_file" "k8s_yaml" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/car.tpl")}"

  vars = {
    ...
    nets     = "${var.nets}"
    ...
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "k8s" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo '${data.template_file.k8s_yaml.rendered}' | ... "
  }
}
```

`module bar's variables.tf`

```
variable "nets" {
  description = "nets desc."
  type        = "list"
}
```

After I try to make a terraform plan, I receive:

```
* module.bar.data.template_file.k8s_yaml: vars: 1 error(s) decoding:

* '[nets]' expected type 'string', got unconvertible type '[]interface {}'
```

I found it really weird since I specified `type: list` in all of the vars definition, why does it think it need a string instead?

Here's a fragment of my tpl file:

```
    netsIDs:
    - ${element(var.nets, 0)}
    - ${element(var.nets, 1)}
    - ${element(var.nets, 2)}
```

Comment: I guess this is related: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/9368

Comment: @Grzegorz Oledzki that indeed looks promising but I didn't manage to make it work.

Comment: That `template_file` (which I have never used) seems to coerce the input to string :/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `netsIDs: ${nets}` and `nets = "${jsonencode(var.nets)}"` fix the problem.